# python-logstash not working properly with logstash & elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash

I have set up this file in /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf

```
input {
   tcp {
      port => 5000
      codec => json
   }
   beats {
      port => 5043
   }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ['localhost:9200']
      user => 'elastic'
      password => 'XXXXXX'
   }
}
```

And in my django project/settings.py I have added

```
LOGGING = {
   'version': 1, 
   'handlers': {
      'logstash': {
         'level': 'INFO',
         'class': 'logstash.TCPLogstashHandler',
         'host': 'localhost',
         'port': 5000,
         'version': 1,
         'message_type': 'logstash',
         'fqdn': True,
         'tags': ['myapp'],
         }
      },
      'loggers': {
         'myapp': {
            'handlers': ['logstash'],
            'level': 'INFO',
         }
      }
   }
```

Why is the data not showing up as another indices when I try to go to
localhost:9200/_cat/indices ?

Comment: Do you have any logs from logstash? (By default, I think they are logstash/logs)

Comment: Also, how are you running logstash? You have to specify the configuration file logstash is supposed to use.

Comment: Im just using service start logtstash

Comment: If you're on linux-like platform, putting your configuration file in `/etc/logstash/conf.d` should work.